# How send an object from PHP to Java web service using SOAP?

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, soap-client

I have a running web service (using EclipseLink as JPA provider) and would like to call the methods that updates data in the database from PHP using SOAP. 
A method in the web service may look something like this:

```
public void updatePerson(Person p){
   EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersonLib");
   EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
   if(!em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
      em.getTransaction().begin();
   }
   em.merge(p);
   em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

From PHP, I guess I have to create an object of type `stdClass` and send it as the parameter for a Person. Am I right? But I don´t get it work with these lines of code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("url.to.wsdl", array("trace" => 1));
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->Person = new stdClass(); 
$obj->Person->personId = 1;
$obj->Person->name = "Peter";
$client->updatePerson($obj);
```

I don´t know if this is the correct way to send an object from PHP to Java (well, it calls the method updatePerson(Person p) in the java application, but p doesn´t contain the data I entered in PHP).

Comment: Can you show us your WSDL? Also you might want to check the examples [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) where the option `"classmap"` is used in the `SoapClient` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it's possible please show us the WSDL file.

Usually when I work with SoapClient in PHP I use arrays even if the web service expects an object, so, instead of creating a new stdClass try sending the following array:

```
$client = new SoapClient("url.to.wsdl");
$obj    = new array("personId" => 1, "name" => "Peter");

$client->updatePerson($obj);
```

And that should send the object with the required data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got it working some days ago. But I did´t no I could send an array instead of objects of type stdClass! :-) Thank you for that!